Unable to control TFT screen using RP2040
I am tinkering with the raspberry pi pico (the one with RP2040 chip). I am trying to use a TFT 1.24 screen controlled by the GC9A01A driver. I have followed the datasheet and the code I was able to produce was this:
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/spi.h"

#define SPI spi0
#define SCL 10
#define SDA 11
#define DCX 12
#define CSX 13
#define RST 15

void init_display();
void send_data(uint8_t *, size_t);
void send_command(uint8_t);

int main(){

        spi_init(SPI, 400000);
        gpio_set_function(SCL, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
        gpio_set_function(SDA, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
        gpio_set_function(DCX, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);

        gpio_init(CSX);
        gpio_set_dir(CSX, 1);
        gpio_put(CSX, 1);

        gpio_init(DCX);
        gpio_set_dir(DCX, 1);

        gpio_init(RST);
        gpio_set_dir(RST, 1);

        gpio_put(RST, 0);
        sleep_ms(100);
        gpio_put(RST, 1);

        init_display();

        //Drawing a red pixel
        uint8_t column_data[] = {25>>8, 25 & 0xFF, 25>>8, 25 & 0xFF};
        uint8_t page_data[] = {25>>8, 25 & 0xFF, 35>>8, 35 & 0xFF};
        uint8_t color[] = {0xF8, 0x00};

        send_command(0x2A);
        send_data(column_data, 4);
        send_command(0x2B);
        send_data(page_data, 4);

        send_command(0x2C);
        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                send_data(color, 2);
}

void init_display(){
        // Software reset
        send_command(0x01);
        sleep_ms(150);

        // Exit sleep mode
        send_command(0x11);
        sleep_ms(150);

        // Set color mode (RGB565)
        send_command(0x3A);
        uint8_t data = 0x55;
        send_data(&data, 1);

        // Display ON
        send_command(0x29);
}

void send_data(uint8_t *data, size_t len){
        gpio_put(DCX, 1);
        gpio_put(CSX, 0);
        spi_write_blocking(SPI, data, len);
        gpio_put(CSX, 1);
}

void send_command(uint8_t command){
        gpio_put(DCX, 0);
        gpio_put(CSX, 0);
        spi_write_blocking(SPI, &command, 1);
        gpio_put(CSX, 1);
}

The goal is to draw a vertical red line from pixel 25 to 35. Not matter how I check the connections and polish the code, the display just lights up (the backlight I mean) and do nothing. As reference, the datasheet I am using is this one: https://www.buydisplay.com/download/ic/GC9A01A.pdf

I would look at Write Display Brightness (51h), as the default is the lowest brightness and RGB Interface Signal Control (B0h), RCM.

@bstipe I found out that the problem is the actually interface respect to the pico. Running the function spi_is_busy I get false, hence is busy.  So every command I have sent were unsuccessful send. Though now I do not know how to get the interface out of busy state...
